# Make Chrome new tab links open in Safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari

Is there a way to make "open in a new tab" links in Chrome open in Safari?  I'd like to use Chrome as an "email" program with just my gmail page, but I want to use Safari as my main web browser, so I would like all links to open in Safari.  Can this be done?  I don't mind doing a little hacking if it's necessary, and I also don't mind running Chromium instead if it's easier.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is:

1. Make sure Safari is default browser
2. Right click tab URL in chrome, and click "Open URL"

This will automatically open that link in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Although technically not opening a new tab in chrome I think this will achieve the result you are looking for if I have understood you correctly. I would suggest following these 2 steps:

1. Make sure that Safari is your default browser.
2. Make Gmail an application shortcut from the tools menu in Chrome (Browse to your gmail account inbox in chrome then click on the spanner then Tools then Create application shortcut) It will put a shortcut to your gmail (on your desktop or where ever you specify). When you need to access it just click on the shortcut and chrome will open it.

That way you can access any HTML file with safari by default and gmail with chrome.

Comment: "Create Application Shortcut…" is dimmed out for some reason.  By the way, the Chrome guys need to learn how to write a Mac OS X application.  This tools menu, which until you just pointed it out me I did not know existed, belongs in the *menu bar*.

Comment: But if it did work, it would indeed solve my problem, assuming links that normally would open in a new tab opened in Safari.  I saw some question here with an answer to the effect of "you can't do that with Application Shortcuts."

Comment: Ah here we go.  http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95710.  "This feature is only available for Google Chrome on Windows and Linux."  So I guess the Mac OS X version doesn't support it yet.  But I seem to remember reading that Chromium does support it, so I'll give that a try.

Comment: It seems that even the latest build of Chromium on Mac OS X does not support this feature.  So I guess I need a different solution.

Comment: Seems silly to me that they can't make it work for Macs. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[John Gruber](http://daringfireball.net/2010/08/open_urls_in_safari_tabs) have a service like the one you want.

[gist id 507356](https://gist.github.com/507356)